# Java: IOException after server update

Tags: java, applet, ioexception

We just updated our server from Sun, running Solaris 9, 32 bit. (installed in 2005) to the new one CentOS 5, (linux) on 64 bit.

The newest Java version is 1.6.0_20 (but we no longer can access the info about the older version of Java).

There is a part of an Java applet (OPMClient) beginning to threw IOExeption:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class OPMClient extends Applet {
    ...
    public static final int PORT = 8888;
    MineCanvas minecanvas;
    ...
    public void clientSend() {
    try {
        s = new Socket(this.getCodeBase().getHost(), PORT);
        in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        listener = new SolutionListener(in, minecanvas);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();} //showStatus("IOException in clientSend()");}
    ...
    }        

    public boolean action(Event e, Object arg) {
    ...
    if (arg.equals("Submit")) {
    if (action(null, "Update Grid")) {
        minecanvas.Submit();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
     ...
}

class MineCanvas extends Canvas {
    ...
    public void Submit() {
    if (position == -1) {
        errorString = "No ore has been entered!";
        mode = ERROR;
        repaint();
    } else {
        ComputeGridValue();
        parent.clientSend();
    }
}
    ...
   }
```

We tried to figure why this is happening, but after hours of working on this, without success.  Could anyone help us to solve this problem?  The stacktrace is below

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at OPMClient.clientSend(OPMClient.java:128)
at MineCanvas.Submit(OPMClient.java:423)
at OPMClient.action(OPMClient.java:118)
at java.awt.Component.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.postEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.postEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.postEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at OPMClient.clientSend(OPMClient.java:138)
at MineCanvas.Submit(OPMClient.java:423)
at OPMClient.action(OPMClient.java:118)
at java.awt.Component.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.postEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.postEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.postEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Will be much appreciated. 
P.S.: Hope this is not an obvious problem.

Sincerely yours,
Yan

Comment: Can you post the detailed stackTrace?

Comment: Change `catch (IOException e) showStatus("IOException in clientSend()");` to `catch (IOException e) e.printStackTrace();` I don't know how you expect to debug this with such inadequate error reporting.  That this would not have occurred to you after 'hours' of working on it, is a worrying thing.

Comment: `import java.lang.*;`  Redundant.  Classes in the `lang` package are automatically imported.

Comment: OK thanks I just deleted the java.lang.* from the .java... still trying to compile the AnApplet.java.  Apparently, updating server also messed up that file - a bunch of errors??? Let me...try to figure this out first.. (was using the old .class file ).

Comment: ok question updated.  see above.

Answer (score 0):

Which specific line throws the IOException? Could you try not catching it so I know?
The line "s = new Socket(this.getCodeBase().getHost(), PORT);" will throw it if an I/O error occurred when creating the socket, probably because this.getCodeBase() had an I/O exception (maybe because of bad url?). The IOException would only occur in the inputstream part if an I/O error occurred when creating the input stream, the socket is closed, the socket is not connected, or the socket input has been shutdown using shutdownInput(). Likewise, it would only occur in the outputstream part if an I/O error occurs when creating the output stream or if the socket is not connected.

Comment: OK, I have updated the question to print the stacktrace (see above). Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I have found out where the problem is: s = new Socket(...) so it is the problem with creating the socket, not output stream.